# Roots over $\mathbb{C}$ equation $x^{4} - 4x^{3} + 2x^{2} + 4x + 4=0 $.

Tags: complex-numbers

I need roots over $\mathbb{C}$ equation  $$x^{4} - 4x^{3} + 2x^{2} + 4x + 4 = 0$$

From Fundamental theorem of algebra we have statement that the equation have 4 roots over complex.

But I prepare special reduction: 
$$ \color{red}{ x^{4} - 4x^{3} + 2x^{2} + 4x + 4} = (x-1)^{4}-4(x-1)^{2} + 7 $$
for substitution $y = (x-1)^{2}$ we have: 
$y^{2} - 4y + 7 = 0 $

$y_{0} = 2+i\sqrt{3}$

$y_1 = 2 - i\sqrt{3}$

and we have
$y_{0}^{1/2} + 1 = x_{0} $,  $-y_{0}^{1/2} + 1 = x_{1}$,
$y_{1}^{1/2} + 1 = x_{2}$,  $-y_{1}^{1/2} +1 = x_{3} $

I am not sure what is good results. 
Please check my solution.

EDIT:
The LHS is not correct, I modify this equation. We should have $p(x) = x^{4} - 4x^{3} + 2x^{2} + 4x + 4 = (x-1)^{4}-4(x-1)^{2} + 7 $

EDIT2: 
I need show that the $p(x)$ is reducible (or not) over $\mathbb{R}[x]$ for two polynomials of degrees 2.
But I am not sure how show that $\left(x-1-\sqrt{2-i\sqrt{3} }\right) \left(x-1+\sqrt{(2+i\sqrt3}\right)$ is (not) polynomial of degree 2.

Comment: So you have roots of $\pm \sqrt{3\pm \sqrt 3 i}$.  Do you know how to find them.

Comment: @fleablood but I have intuition about two real roots, how to prove that ?

Comment: @fleablood, it's $2\pm\sqrt3i$ inside the square root, not $3$.

Comment: @Blabla, what is the basis for your intuition regarding real roots?

Comment: Is your 'special reduction' correct? The coefficients of $x$ don't seem to cancel on the RHS.

Comment: @Berci, good catch. I'm sorry I didn't check it myself. (I was caught up in other, easier-to-spot errors.)

Comment: I suspect the equation was $x^{4}-4x^{3}+2x^{2}+4x+4=0$.

Comment: I actually meant, do you know how find the square root of $2 +i\sqrt 3$?  You have $(x-1)^2 = 2 \pm i \sqrt 3$ so $x = 1 \pm \sqrt{2 \pm i\sqrt 3}$.  If you know how to find the two square roots of $2+i\sqrt 3$ and of $2-i\sqrt 3$ you are done.  So again I ask.  Do you you know how to find square roots of complex numbers.

Comment: @fleablood Yes, I know, using de Moivre formula

Comment: Then.... do them.

Comment: So I need compute $(r(\cos(\theta)+ i \sin(\theta)))^{1/2} = ±\sqrt{r}(\cos(\theta/2) + i \sin(\theta/2))$, but $\theta = tan^{-1}(b/a)$, where $z = a+bi$

Comment: The polynomial $p(x)=x^4-4x^3+2x^2+4x+4=(x-1)^4-4(x-1)^2+7$ does *not* have any real roots. The polynomial in the title, $x^4-4x^3+2x^2+4$, on the other hand, *does* have two real roots. Please decide which polynomial your question is about, and edit accordingly, removing the one you're not really asking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

COMMENT.-These are the two real roots given by Wolfram. It is impossible that you can calculate them by simple means. The two non-real roots are equally complicated.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The equality that you have used is not correct.$$x^{4}-4x^{3}+2x^{2}+4 \ne  (x-1)^{4}-4(x-1)^{2} + 7$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention, I fixed the equation.

Answer (score 0):

Solving algebraically is perhaps not too messy if one is happy to have roots in terms of the solution to a cubic:-

Using the substitution $t=x-1$ we have $$ t^{4}- 4t^{2}-4t+3=0$$ and therefore $$ (t^{2}- 2)^2=4t+1.$$

For any $z$, $$ (t^{2}- 2+2z^2)^2=4z^2t^2+4t+4z^4-8z^2+1.$$

Let $z$ be a solution (found by Cardan's method) of the cubic in $z^2$
$$4z^6-8z^4+z^2-1=0$$
Then $$ (t^{2}- 2+2z^2)^2=(2zt+\frac{1}{z})^2.$$
This is a quadratic in $t$ giving, for example, $t=z+\sqrt {2-z^2+\frac{1}{z}}$ and $t=z-\sqrt {2-z^2+\frac{1}{z}}$.

(One has to be careful choosing the correct signs for whatever root of the cubic is chosen- the signs I have used give real roots for the real root of the cubic.)

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to the revised question**

You have correctly obtained $x=1\pm \sqrt{2\pm i\sqrt3}$.

By the standard method find the complex square roots. This gives one form of the full answer as $$x=1\pm \sqrt[4]7(\frac{2+\sqrt7\pm i\sqrt3}{\sqrt{14+4\sqrt7}}).$$